# Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

I keep getting an error when I tried to build my react-native app with `npx expo run:android`

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-webview'.
      > Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
         > Namespace not specified. Please specify a namespace in the module's build.gradle file like so:

           android {
               namespace 'com.example.namespace'
           }
```

However, in `android/app/build.gradle`

```
...
android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion
    namespace 'com.wilburcoding.BirdSoundSearch'
...
```

There doesn't appear to be any answers online that have valid/working answers to this problem.
It does appear this issue may have originated from `react-native-webview`. Is this an issue with the dependency or a gradle issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newer versions of React Native will require a `namespace` be set in `build.gradle` files. To correct the issue, you should try bumping the dependency in question (in this case, `react-native-webview`) to a newer version which contains the `namespace` entry.
You can also try removing `namespace` from `android/app/build.gradle`, as I don't believe it's strictly needed in React Native 71 or 72.

To learn more about why these changes have been made, take a look at this GitHub discussion: https://github.com/react-native-community/discussions-and-proposals/issues/671

Comment: Looks like that's the issue. Unfortunately, react-native-webview has yet to add the namespace so I added it manually. Seems to work now.

Comment: but in my case there's a lot of packages which needs `package` name to be removed from AndroidManifest.xml and `namespace` to be added in their respective build.gradle in node_modules.

Answer (score 8):

I was having the same issue here. Go to the list of graddle scripts in your android app. Locate the one that is giving you issue (in my case it was  `build.gradle (Module: react-native-maps)`

Then open it and add your namespace there, under android.

```
...
android {
    ...
    namespace 'com.example.namespace'
...
}
```

Comment: Yup, basically what I had to do to solve the issue manually!