A problem occurred configuring project ':gallery_saver'

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':gallery_saver'.


Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

 If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.[enter image description here]
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.[enter image description here]

BUILD FAILED in 5m 44s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
enter image description here
how to fix this error

This is likely an issue with the gradle configuration of the package. Newer versions of gradle require the property of "namespace" in the build.gradle. If that is missing then an error will occur. I recommend that you reach out to the package author's GitHub and open an issue there.

I have face the same isues today and yesterday . I resolved it . Look at my answer . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77003212/namespace-not-specified-please-specify-a-namespace-in-the-modules-build-gradle/79027489#79027489

Before that update all your dependencies to latest versions

image_gallery_saver module or dependency is missing a namespace property in its build.gradle file You can add it manually.
In Windows, go to:
C:\Users<YourUsername>\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\image_gallery_saver-2.0.3\android
or
C:\Users<YourUsername>\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache
This is the path where flutter normally download the dependencies
Add your package name i.e namespace = "com.example.myapp" into android block.
And run your project. If you get another error of jvm related, add this in
android block:
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

